# C# HttpWebRequest Parameters Empty

Tags: c#, api, http, httpwebrequest

I am struggling with the syntax to make a POST web request with parameters. I get a response back but not data and it should I'm suspecting it is because I am not passing the parameters right.

What is also strange if I use a string "[100,200]" and send that over and let C# compiler convert the string over to int[] it's almost like the data isn't getting sent.

The api method looks like:

```
public string GetPersonInfo(int64[] personsIds)
```

Then here is my api request (parameter part)

```
HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("MyApicall.com/api/Persons/GetPersonInfo");
int[] numArray = new int[]{100,200};
byte[] sendInfo = new byte[numArray.length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(numArray,0,sendInfo,sendInfo.length);

request.Headers["Accept-Languages"] = "en-Us";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = sendInfo.length;

Stream curStream = request.GetRequestStream();
curStream.Write(sendInfo,0,sendInfo.length);
curStream.Close();
```

Comment: Another note was able to replicate this with a api tester, personsId ends up showing {long[0]} instead of the say 100,200

Comment: Did you consider to call `Flush` on the stream?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yeah makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tired to set the [AllowWriteStreamBuffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowwritestreambuffering?view=netcore-3.1) to false? (NOTE: Please be aware that there is a counterpart property of this: `AllowReadStreamBuffering`) Please also make sure that the receiver side is prepared for receiving contentType  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`